# Include a directory structure in a zip file based on a fixed relative path

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, zip

Given the directory at a path `a:\\b\\c\\d\\e`, I want to create a zipfile in python 3.5+ that looks like this:

```
file.zip # want this
 +d
  +-...files from d\
  +-e
    +-...files from e\
```

I tried this by walking the target path like this, using `os` and `zipfile`:

```
start_path = "a:\\b\\c\\d"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):
    for file in files:
        ziph.write(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file)))
```

Due to the the `relpath` and working dir being in `b`, the code will create a zip file as follows:

```
file.zip # do not want this
 +c
  +-...files from c\
  +-d
    +-...files from d\
    +-e
      +-...files from e\
```

My Question is: How can I force the zipwriter to create a directory structure as shown at the beginning, starting with dir `d` while I know the full path only at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZipFile.write` accepts a [second parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write), which is the directory you want it to be in inside the `zip`. So you can have something like:

```
start_path = "a:\\b\\c\\d"
import os
zip_start_path = start_path.split(os.sep)[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you! I seem to have overlooked that `arcname` parameter. 
Could I make the path splitting seperator os independent?

Comment: Yep, you get the separator with `os.sep` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep)

Comment: Thanks, that's helping me out!